# How to add facebook application to profile page

Tags: facebook

I developed a facebook landing page with an iFrame and now I want to add the page to my facebook profile page. When I click "Add to my page" at the application's profile page, my profile is not listed there.

Can anyone give me a tip please?

Comment: You want to add a tab to your Facebook product/company page, or to your personal profile?

Comment: Have you defined a `Page Tab URL` and `Secure Page Tab URL` for your application?

Comment: Yes, I filled that in correctly.

Comment: Can you find a way to add custom tab to your facebook personal profile (not a page)? Some Facebook apps like Pinterest, Runtastic, Yelp, Instagram, Foursquare, Codecademy, have custom sections (in "MORE" of Drop-Down control of Users' Personal Profile) and post there text,pictures, videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created your application it should also have created an app profile page.  You can add your application there.  To find your application profile page you can navigate to this URL https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id={APPLICATION_ID}
Or, in your application settings click on the "View app profile page" in the bottom left sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments above :

> "To my personal profile."  – enne87

You can not have this functionality.  You can only add application to facebook pages, not to peoples profiles.

Comment: Well, a person I know managed it actually. On the left side of his profile he has "Favourites, "Pages", "Groups", "Applications" and under "Pages" there is one application. The problem is that I can't ask him right now...

Comment: @enne87, you have a problem with the fundamental meanings of profile and page.  What you are referring to is the bookmarks on the left sidebar.  Your application has NO control over the sidebar.  The items location are determined by usage or user preference.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. One more question: My application includes a simple form. It can be found here: http://apps.facebook.com/327374733956408/ Now I would like to embed it to a page. I searched for some tutorials but I couldn't find a solution. Do I have to make a fan page first to include it?

Comment: Thanks Lix. I created a fanpage now. So could you please tell me how I would include my landing page now?

Comment: From your application profile page (details in my 2nd answer below), you click the "Add to my Page" link (also bottom left sidebar).  The rest should be self-explanatory.  Please mark this question as answered if you feel that it assisted you.