# How to make a Facebook app that installs a page tab on the user's page (of which he is the admin)?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have made a simple Facebook app that takes in user data and does something (irrelevant to the question). Now, what I want is that the app must get installed on a user's page (i.e., the page for which the user is an admin) like this:

[image: The app installed on the page]

[Here](http://apps.facebook.com/ecwid-shop/) is the app that does the above.

How can I do this for my app? Is there something available with the Facebook API? Or is it a hack?

Comment: Duplicate, you can not do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384467/how-to-add-facebook-application-to-profile-page

Comment: @IvanHanák firstly, it isn't a dupe. Please read both the questions carefully. And secondly, how can I not do that? I did show you an example, didn't I? How did that guy pull it off?

Comment: When you say installed on a user's page do you mean on a Page where the user is an admin? currently it's not possible with user profile pages. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

Comment: @Ranveer, what you are talking about is adding an app into a page, as a page tab. Your term `user's page` I treated as a `timeline`. By all means, @Malcolm posted a right way, how to do that

Comment: @Malcolm yes, I mean the pages for which the user is the admin. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an app as a page tab you could try one of the following.

**Tab Dialog using the JavaScript SDK.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addtab()
  {
FB.ui({
  method: 'pagetab',
  redirect_uri: 'YOUR_URL'
}, function(response){});
  }
</script>

  <a href="#" onClick="addtab()">Add As Page Tab</a>
```

The above example assumes that the person has already logged in to your app.

**URL Redirect.**

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL">Add As Page Tab</a>
```

**Or like in your example website you could use something like the following.**

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_APP_ID&pages">Add As Page Tab</a>
```

Make sure and change **YOUR_APP_ID** and **YOUR_URL** with the ID and URL of the app you want to add as a Page Tab.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page